# Can I pass a Binding variable as a parameter in a function? (do I need to in this case?)

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, binding

I'm new to Swift / Firebase and need some help with my code.

I have a simple create new account page, and I am using Firebase.

I want to create a user when a button is tapped - change button colour/text to reflect this - then return to HomeView

Now, I want to include all the `Auth.auth()` in a separate function on a separate swift file - to keep my View code clean.

Currently, I'm setting the `isShowingNewAccountView = false` to return back to `HomeView` (via a `NavigationLink` on `HomeView`) - `isShowingAccountView` is a Binding variable from `HomeView`.

If I put all the `Auth.auth()` code into a separate function, is it possible to change the value of the isShowingAccountView to 'false' when a user is created from within the function? Is there a more elegant alternative

```swift
Button(action: {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: newUser.userEmail, password: newUser.userPassword) { authDataResult, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error detected")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)

            isShowingNewAccountView = true         //Binding variable from HomeView - Keep showing NewAccountView
            newUser.successNewAccountCreated = false
            return
        }
        else
        {
            print("Account Successfully Created")
            isShowingNewAccountView = false        //Binding variable from HomeView - Revert back to HomeView
            newUser.successNewAccountCreated = true
            return
        }
    }
}, label: {
    CustomButton(buttonText: (!newUser.successNewAccountCreated ? "Create New Account" : "New Account Created"), colourVar: newUser.successNewAccountCreated ? .green : (isInputAppropriate() ? .accentColor : .gray)
})
```

On `HomeView` I have:

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: NewAccountView(isShowingNewAccountView: $isShowingNewAccountView), isActive: $isShowingNewAccountView) {
    //passing isShowingAccountView as a binding $
    EmptyView()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if I really get what you are trying to do. 
If you make a ViewModel for the authentication as an `ObservableObject`, the functions (and published vars) will be available everywhere you use the `ObservableObject`. If you want to handle something when a var changes, you also can work with Combine. If you have a screenshot or scratch of what you want to achieve, maybe I can help better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach may help you:

#### Three views (just as an example):

1. ContentView: It shows either Page1 or Page2, depending on the var `isShowingNewAccountView`.
2. Page1: It is the page you use to create a new user, it will be shown when `isShowingNewAccountView` is `false`. It calls the function `signUp` from the `AuthenticationViewModel`.
3. Page2: It is the page that will be opened when a new User has been created and `isShowingNewAccountView` is `true`

#### One ViewModel (also just as an example)

The authentication is handled in the AuthenticationViewModel. It is handling the functions to `signUp`, `signIn` and `signOut`. It also holds `isShowingNewAccountView`.

### Views

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Page1: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    @State private var buttonPressed = false
    @State private var email: String = "sebastian@hello.me"
    @State private var password: String = "password"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            
            Text("Register")
                .font(Font.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                .padding()
                .padding(.vertical, 50)
            
            TextField("E-Mail", text: $email)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                buttonPressed.toggle()
                authenticationViewModel.signUp(email: email, password: password){ success, uid in
                    if success {
                        print("UID: \(uid)")
                    } else {
                        print("Uh-oh")
                    }
                    buttonPressed = false
                }
            }) {
                Text(buttonPressed ? "In Progress" : "Sign Up - Create User")
                    .foregroundColor(buttonPressed ? Color.pink : Color.cyan)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Page2: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            authenticationViewModel.isShowingNewAccountView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Back to other page")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    var body: some View {
        if authenticationViewModel.isShowingNewAccountView {
            Page2()
        } else {
            Page1()
        }
    }
}
```

### ViewModel for Authentication

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var isShowingNewAccountView: Bool = false
    
    // Sign Up
    func signUp(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Bool, String)->Void) {
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            
            // ERROR AND SUCCESS HANDLING
            if error != nil {
                // ERROR HANDLING
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                completion(false, "ERROR")
            } else {
                // SUCCESS HANDLING
                self.isShowingNewAccountView = true
                completion(true, authResult?.user.uid ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Sign In
    func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Bool, String)->Void) {
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
            
            // ERROR AND SUCCESS HANDLING
            if error != nil {
                // ERROR HANDLING
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                completion(false, "ERROR")
            }
            
            completion(true, authResult?.user.uid ?? "")
        }
    }
    
    // Sign Out
    func signOut(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) ->Void) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        completion(true)
    }
    
    // Create new user
    func createNewUser(name: String, id: String) {
        do {
            let newUser = User(name: name, id: id)
            try db.collection("users").document(newUser.id!).setData(from: newUser) { _ in
                print("User \(name) created")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing user to Firestore: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

### Alternative with a NavigationLink

In your approach you are using a NavigationLink. That would work as well. In that case the ContentView as well as the Page1 view are slightly different (Page2 stays as it is):

#### ContentView Update

In the ContentView it is not necessary do make the decision which view will be shown.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    var body: some View {
       Page1()
    }
}
```

#### Page1 Update

On Page1 we now need the `NavigationView` and the `NavigationLink`. As soon as `isShowingNewAccountView` becomes true, it opens Page2, but for me, the NavigationLink is something you can press, like a button. But anyway:

```
struct Page1: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    @State private var buttonPressed = false
    @State private var email: String = "sebastian@hello.me"
    @State private var password: String = "password"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(){
            VStack(){
                
                Text("Register")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.vertical, 50)
                
                TextField("E-Mail", text: $email)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
                
                Button(action: {
                    buttonPressed.toggle()
                    authenticationViewModel.signUp(email: email, password: password){ success, uid in
                        if success {
                            print("UID: \(uid)")
                        } else {
                            print("Uh-oh")
                        }
                        buttonPressed = false
                    }
                }) {
                    Text(buttonPressed ? "In Progress" : "Sign Up - Create User")
                        .foregroundColor(buttonPressed ? Color.pink : Color.cyan)
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Page2(), isActive: $authenticationViewModel.isShowingNewAccountView){
                                EmptyView()}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the gif:

[image: SignUp with NavigationView]